# Jenkins slave can’t access Jenkins master kubernetes pod

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I have a kubernetes pods setup with jenkins master and jenkins slave which is created on deployment.

My slave process is not able to connect to the master process. I have tried configuring the jenkins url to the service name with port, service ip address with port but both didn’t work.

My service looks like this:

```
jenkins1                  LoadBalancer  100.70.213.156  a1a3cd39dfe7011eaacd202be15828c0-1501075918.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com  80:30416/TCP,50000:32699/TCP  1h
```

The error that I can see in the slave pod is

```
SEVERE: Failed to connect to http://jenkins.infrastructure.svc.cluster.local:8080/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: jenkins.infrastructure.svc.cluster.local
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to http://jenkins.infrastructure.svc.cluster.local:8080/tcpSlaveAgentListener/: jenkins.infrastructure.svc.cluster.local
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:217)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:693)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:518)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jenkins.infrastructure.svc.cluster.local
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:214)
    ... 2 more
```

This is my service configuration

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a ‘#’ will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2020-09-24T14:13:21Z
  name: jenkins1
  namespace: infrastructure
  resourceVersion: “160204667”
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/infrastructure/services/jenkins1
  uid: 1a3cd39d-fe70-11ea-acd2-02be15828c0e
spec:
  clusterIP: 100.70.213.156
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: jenkins-master
    nodePort: 30416
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: jenkins-jnlp
    nodePort: 32699
    port: 50000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 50000
  selector:
    app: jenkins
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: a1a3cd39dfe7011eaacd202be15828c0-1501075918.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

My jenkins configuration looks like this
[image]
[image]

Build repo that overrides jenkins config
[image]

Comment: Use `jenkins1` instead of `jenkins`

Comment: Where should I use jenkins1 instead of jenkins?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I have used this jenkins url http://jenkins1:8080 and the same result

Comment: @Bob, he said `jenkins1` instead of `jenkins` because your service is named jenkins1.